# Proof of Multiplication Rule for Independent Events for all n

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to prove the multiplication rule for mutually independent events for all n.

I know the base step for $A$ and $B$ if they are independent events, but is it enough to say that :

- if $A, B, C$ are mutually independent,
- then

  - $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B)$,
  - and $P((A \cap B) \cap C) = (P(A) \times P(B)) \times  P(C)$?

If so, then I can generalize this to any event. If not, it's looking like proof by induction.

Comment: Pairwise independent random variables don't necessarily remain multiplicative when you take a three way intersection.

Comment: But I am only looking at independent events right now, as I am trying to show that this holds only for independent events

Comment: As said above, you need to state that $A, B, C$ are pairwise independent only or mutually independent. If it is the latter case then the result is guaranteed by definition.

Comment: Do you think if they are mutually independent I can go about proving it this way?

Comment: The thing you want to prove is already included when you say that they are mutually independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events $A$, $B$, $C$ are pairwise independent if
$$
P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B), \ P(B\cap C)=P(B)P(C), \ \mathrm{and} \ P(C\cap A)=P(C)P(A).
$$

The events $A$, $B$, $C$ are (mutually) independent if

1. $A$, $B$, $C$ are pairwise independent, and
2. $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B)P(C)$.

We have some examples showing that 1. does not imply 2., also there are examples showing that 2. does not imply 1.

Comment: This is to prove the statement in a question. The statement is that let there be a probability space where are the singleton sets are events, i.e. w in omega. Suppose A_n where A_n is a countable sequence of independent events, show that if P(A) = 1/2 for all n, then P(w)=0.

Comment: Am I okay to assume that all these A_n are mutually independent?

Comment: Yes. it is okay to assume that. I think that is what it means by 'sequence of independent events'.

Comment: so can I just prove it like I stated in the post?

Comment: The point is that you do not need to prove anything. Just by saying that they are independent, is enough to conclude that $P(A_1\cap \cdots \cap A_n)=P(A_1) \cdots P(A_n)$.